# Partial derivatives with level curves

Tags: calculus

How do I solve this problem : Use partial derivative to find the line

1. perpendicular and
2. tangent to level curve of $z= \sqrt{5}$ at $(x,y,z)=(\sqrt{2}, -\sqrt{2},\sqrt{5})$?

I forgot to add I'm using the sphere equation $x^2+ y^2 + z^2 = 9$.

Comment: It is not clear exactly what you are asking. Are you trying to find the tangent *plane*  to the level *surface* $x^2+y^2+z^2=9$ of $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$at the point $(\sqrt{2}, -\sqrt{2},\sqrt{5})$?

Comment: No I'm trying to find the line perpendicular to the level curve and the tangent line to the level curve.

Comment: OK, so your function is $z=g(x,y)=\sqrt{9-x^2-y^2}$ then?

Comment: Do you know how to find the gradient vector $\nabla g(x,y)$ by taking the partial derivatives of $g$?

Comment: No im barely familiar to it

Comment: And yes that's the function

Comment: It appears that this is what you are studying now. $\nabla g(x,y)=\left\langle \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial x},\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial y}\right\rangle$.

Comment: The gradient is the normal vector to the level curve for any given $x=x_0,\,y=y_0$. For your problem, $x_0=\sqrt{2}, y_0=-\sqrt{2}$ and the vector equation of the normal line is $(x-x_0)g_x(x_0,y_0)+(y-y_0)g_y(x_0,y_0)$. For the perpendicular line, you need a direction vector whose dot-product with the gradient is $0$ such as $\left\langle \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial y},-\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial x}\right\rangle$.

Comment: More explanation confuses me more. Can you show me some step by step on how to do this please.

Comment: On the equation of the normal line I accidentally left off the $=0$.

Comment: OK, give me a few minutes to write it out.

Comment: Hey John you don't need to write out the answer, I'm starting to understand now. Thank you again for everything

Comment: OK, I went ahead and posted what I had finished so far. The tangent vector is done the same way but using the appropriate direction vector.

Answer (score 0):

Given

$$z=g(x,y)=\sqrt{9-x^2-y^2}$$

find the equations of the normal line and the tangent line to the level curve $z=\sqrt{5}$ at the point $(\sqrt{2},-\sqrt{2})$

The gradient vector is defined as follows

$$\nabla g(x,y)=\langle g_x,g_y\rangle=\left\langle \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial x},\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial y}\right\rangle$$

One property of the gradient vector is that it is perpendicular to the level (or, in the case of a function of three variables, the level **surface**) at any given point $(x_0,y_0)$ of the level curve, so it forms a direction vector for the normal line containing that point.

Furthermore, the vector $\langle g_y,-g_x\rangle$ is the direction vector for the tangent line at that point.

For this particular function $g$

1. $g_x=\dfrac{-x}{\sqrt{9-x^2-y^2}}$ and
2. $g_y=\dfrac{-y}{\sqrt{9-x^2-y^2}}$

so at $(x_0,y_0)=\left(\sqrt{2},-\sqrt{2}\right)$

we have $g_x=\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{5}}$ and $g_y=-\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{5}}$

The equation of a line with direction vector $\langle a,b\rangle$ and containing point $(x_0,y_0)$ is

$$  a(x-x_0)+b(y-y_0)=0$$

so the equation of the normal line is

$$ \sqrt{\dfrac{2}{5}}(x-\sqrt{2})- \sqrt{\dfrac{2}{5}}(y+\sqrt{2})=0$$

which can be simplified to

$$ x-y=2\sqrt{2} $$

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated!

Comment: You're welcome.